# Orbit Space of cylinder

Tags: algebraic-topology

I have trouble at understanding example 3 in Section 81 in Topology, Munkres.

Let $X$ be the cylinder $S^1 \times I$;

let $h: X \rightarrow X$ be the homeomorphism $h(x, t)=(-x, t)$; and let

$k: X \rightarrow X$ be the homeomorphism $k(x, t)=(-x, 1-t)$. The groups $G_1=\{e, h\}$ and $G_2=\{e, k\}$ are isomorphic to the integers modulo $2$; both act properly discontinuously on $X$.

But $X/G_1$ is homeomorphic to $X$, while $X/G_2$ is homeomorphic to the Mobius band.

**I cannot understand why $X/G_1$ is homeomorphic to $X$ and $X/G_2$ is homeomorphic to the Mobius band**

Comment: For the first question: there's a map $f:X\to X$ given by $f(z,t)=(z^2,t)$ which is a quotient map (since $X$ is compact) and so it induces homeomorphism $(X/\sim)\simeq X$, where $(z,t)\sim (z',t')$ iff $z=\pm z'$ and $t=t'$. Thus $X/\sim$ is literally equal to $X/G_1$. For the second part, the twist on $t$ coordinate induces homeomorphism with the Möbious band, but seems harder to find a concrete quotient map.

Comment: I really appreciate for your help. Thanks a lot!!